# Searching a html table with js but show if no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is an example js to search through and filter the results. 
http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/7BUmG/1133/

How is it possible implement something like this?

```
if(results == null){
   console.log("no results");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example, it checks if any rows are visible after searching and hides/shows a "no results" message based on that.

```
if ($rows.find(':visible').length === 0) {
  $("#noResults").show();
}
else{
  $("#noResults").hide();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asrabhdn/

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
    if ($rows.find(':visible').length === 0) {
        console.log('no results');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to store the filter() results and check it's length against all rows

```
var $hidden = $rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    return !reg.test(text);
}).hide();

$('#no-results').toggle($hidden.length === $rows.length)
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cvrxu08y/)**</kbd>

Comment: The problem with this is that at the beginning it starts with no results instead showing it after searching and there are no results

Comment: At least on mobile devices